# Occasional Infinite Loop in Pokemon Battle Program

Tags: ruby, infinite-loop

This only happens ~15% of the time when the program is run. I put a stop to the endless terminal loop by limiting the number of "rounds" to 10 via the "counter" variable. Without the counter stopping the loop, it decreases the attack damage into negative exponential values (ex 1.80e-80) and stops subtracting from health.

```
pokemon = ['Bulbasaur', 'Charizard', 'Squirtle']


player_one_selection = rand(3)
player_two_selection = rand(3)

puts player_one_selection
counter = 0
until player_one_selection != player_two_selection
    counter += 1
    player_two_selection = rand(3)
    print "#{counter} "
end

puts player_two_selection

player_one_pkmn = pokemon[player_one_selection]
player_two_pkmn = pokemon[player_two_selection]


puts player_one_pkmn
puts player_two_pkmn

p1_dm = 1
p2_dm = 1

if player_one_pkmn == 'Bulbasaur' && player_two_pkmn == 'Charizard'
    p1_dm = 0.9
    p2_dm = 1.1
end
if player_one_pkmn == 'Squirtle' && player_two_pkmn == 'Charizard'
    p1_dm = 1.1
    p2_dm = 0.9
end
if player_one_pkmn == 'Bulbasaur' && player_two_pkmn == 'Squirtle'
    p1_dm = 1.1
    p2_dm = 0.9
end
if player_one_pkmn == 'Squirtle' && player_two_pkmn == 'Bulbasaur'
    p1_dm = 0.9
    p2_dm = 1.1
end
if player_one_pkmn == 'Charizard' && player_two_pkmn == 'Squirtle'
    p1_dm = 0.9
    p2_dm = 1.1
end
if player_one_pkmn == 'Charizard' && player_two_pkmn == 'Bulbasaur'
    p1_dm = 1.1
    p2_dm = 0.9
end

jugador_uno = {
    "pokemon"           => player_one_pkmn,
    "pokemon-type"      => "",
    "pokemon-health"    => 100,
    "damage-modifier"   => p1_dm,
    "pokemon-lvl"       => rand(5)+5,
    "current-attack" => ["",0]
}
jugador_dos = {
    "pokemon"           => player_two_pkmn,
    "pokemon-type"      => "",
    "pokemon-health"    => 100,
    "damage-modifier"   => p2_dm,
    "pokemon-lvl"       => rand(5)+5,
    "current-attack" => ["",0]
}

puts jugador_uno
puts jugador_dos

puts "\nReady to Battle! \n"

attacks = [
    ['tackle', 20], ['leer', 5], ['bite', 35], ['special-attack', 50]
]
counter = 0
# until jugador_uno['pokemon-health'] <= 0 || jugador_dos['pokemon-health'] <= 0
loop do
    jugador_uno['current-attack'] = attacks[rand(4)]
    jugador_dos['current-attack'] = attacks[rand(4)]

    jugador_uno['current-attack'][1] = jugador_uno['current-attack'][1] * jugador_uno['pokemon-lvl'] / 10 * jugador_uno['damage-modifier']
    jugador_dos['current-attack'][1] = jugador_dos['current-attack'][1] * jugador_dos['pokemon-lvl'] / 10 * jugador_dos['damage-modifier']

    puts "Lvl. #{jugador_uno['pokemon-lvl']} #{jugador_uno['pokemon']} attack: #{jugador_uno['current-attack'][0].capitalize} did #{jugador_uno['current-attack'][1]} damage."
    puts "Lvl. #{jugador_dos['pokemon-lvl']} #{jugador_dos['pokemon']} attack: #{jugador_dos['current-attack'][0].capitalize} did #{jugador_dos['current-attack'][1]} damage.\n"

    jugador_dos['pokemon-health'] -= jugador_uno['current-attack'][1]
    jugador_uno['pokemon-health'] -= jugador_dos['current-attack'][1]

    puts "\n#{jugador_uno['pokemon']} health: #{jugador_uno['pokemon-health']}"
    puts "#{jugador_dos['pokemon']} health: #{jugador_dos['pokemon-health']}\n"

    counter += 1

    break if jugador_uno['pokemon-health'] <= 0 || jugador_dos['pokemon-health'] <= 0 || counter > 10
end
```

Terminal output in the case where it would be stuck in infinite loop

```
Seths-MacBook-Air:learn-ruby$ ruby pokemon_game.rb 
2
0
Squirtle
Bulbasaur
{"pokemon"=>"Squirtle", "pokemon-type"=>"", "pokemon-health"=>100, "damage-modifier"=>0.9, "pokemon-lvl"=>6, "current-attack"=>["", 0]}
{"pokemon"=>"Bulbasaur", "pokemon-type"=>"", "pokemon-health"=>100, "damage-modifier"=>1.1, "pokemon-lvl"=>6, "current-attack"=>["", 0]}

Ready to Battle! 
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Bite did 18.900000000000002 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Tackle did 13.200000000000001 damage.

Squirtle health: 86.8
Bulbasaur health: 81.1
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Special-attack did 27.0 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Leer did 3.3000000000000003 damage.

Squirtle health: 83.5
Bulbasaur health: 54.099999999999994
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Bite did 10.206 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Leer did 2.178 damage.

Squirtle health: 81.322
Bulbasaur health: 43.89399999999999
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Bite did 5.51124 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Leer did 1.43748 damage.

Squirtle health: 79.88452000000001
Bulbasaur health: 38.38275999999999
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Special-attack did 14.58 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Bite did 3.6374184 damage.

Squirtle health: 76.24710160000001
Bulbasaur health: 23.802759999999992
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Tackle did 7.128 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Leer did 0.9487368000000003 damage.

Squirtle health: 75.2983648
Bulbasaur health: 16.674759999999992
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Bite did 1.29637591776 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Bite did 1.29637591776 damage.

Squirtle health: 74.00198888224
Bulbasaur health: 15.378384082239991
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Leer did 0.5123178720000002 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Tackle did 4.70448 damage.

Squirtle health: 69.29750888224
Bulbasaur health: 14.86606621023999
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Bite did 0.7000429955904002 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Leer did 0.3381297955200002 damage.

Squirtle health: 68.95937908671999
Bulbasaur health: 14.166023214649591
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Bite did 0.37802321761881613 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Leer did 0.22316566504320015 damage.

Squirtle health: 68.7362134216768
Bulbasaur health: 13.787999997030775
Lvl. 6 Squirtle attack: Bite did 0.1347274747593461 damage.
Lvl. 6 Bulbasaur attack: Bite did 0.1347274747593461 damage.

Squirtle health: 68.60148594691745
Bulbasaur health: 13.653272522271429
```

Comment: Though this doesn't answer your question, an easier way to get different random selections for the two players is to use [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-sample): `[0,1,2].sample(2)`.

Comment: Please reduce the code to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your question is "Why is this program infinitely looping?", then the answer is that in certain cases the values in your attacks array:

```
attacks = [
    ['tackle', 20], ['leer', 5], ['bite', 35], ['special-attack', 50]
]
```

gradually decrease towards 0.

You can see for yourself by modifying the above code to print out the values in attacks:

```
loop do
  puts "attack choices: #{attacks}"

  jugador_uno['current-attack'] = attacks[rand(4)]
  jugador_dos['current-attack'] = attacks[rand(4)]

  jugador_uno['current-attack'][1] = jugador_uno['current-attack'][1] * jugador_uno['pokemon-lvl'] / 10 * jugador_uno['damage-modifier']
  jugador_dos['current-attack'][1] = jugador_dos['current-attack'][1] * jugador_dos['pokemon-lvl'] / 10 * jugador_dos['damage-modifier']

  # ...
end
```

What you'll find is that in the first iteration, attacks contains the initial values of `['tackle', 20], ['leer', 5], ['bite', 35], ['special-attack', 50]`, but subsequent iterations will replace them with updated values.

For example,

```
attack choices: [["tackle", 20], ["leer", 5], ["bite", 35], ["special-attack", 50]]
attack choices: [["tackle", 20], ["leer", 5], ["bite", 10.395000000000001], ["special-attack", 50]]
attack choices: [["tackle", 20], ["leer", 2.7], ["bite", 1.6980232500000005], ["special-attack", 50]]

# bunch of iterations later

attack choices: [["tackle", 5.219269710359129e-11], ["leer", 2.46107539497387e-11], ["bite", 2.5860511581722106e-16], ["special-attack", 9.938279578366043e-12]]
```

The values are being replaced in the following two lines of code:

```
jugador_uno['current-attack'][1] = jugador_uno['current-attack'][1] * jugador_uno['pokemon-lvl'] / 10 * jugador_uno['damage-modifier']
jugador_dos['current-attack'][1] = jugador_dos['current-attack'][1] * jugador_dos['pokemon-lvl'] / 10 * jugador_dos['damage-modifier']
```

When `jugador_uno['damage-modifier']` or `jugador_dos['damage-modifier']` is less than 1 (for example, 0.9), then you will run into issues.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about resetting the values so that they wouldn't decrease, but I feel like this will come in handle later once I'm not making simple Pokemon games lol. @hjing, I can't vote you up because I don't have enough reputation, and I don't know how to mark this as answered, but you definitely gave a great answer, thanks a lot!